# Is it haram to transliterate Arabic in English?

Tags: halal-haram, arabic, english

I have been told that it is haram to write Arabic in English like e.g. *"Assalam O Alaikum"* and *"JazakALLAH"*.

So is transliterating Arabic in English actually haram?

Comment: Arabic in general which includes *"ahlan wa sahlan"* or Arabic that is part of the Islamic literature (Quran, Hadith ...)?

Comment: It's not haram, actually it's preferd to say "Assalam alykom, Jazaka Allah kol khyr..." even for non muslim instead of "Hello, hi , Bonjour ..."

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I researched, I did not find any related matter regarding that. And it seems (canonically & logically) it is not considered as a haram practice to transliterate Arabic in English in common situations. Because the intention of the person(s) who is transliterating the texts in English, could be solely made the reader understand concerning the pronunciation of the phrases.

Then it couldn’t be considered as a haram deed. Besides, we must pay attention that there are many people of the world who don’t know Arabic language, then we cannot say that they should not know it because they don’t know Arabic language! Consequently there must be a method which could help them understanding the pronunciation of Arabic words and sentences.

Of course it could be surveyed from another aspect. In truth, it could be said that it could be haram in case using in negative or haram ways. Otherwise generally it is counted as Mubah (permissible) deeds.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, languages are just languages.
It is not haram to write Arabic word in English but it will be if you write it wrongly. Like in Arabic language, if you make a little change in word it will change the meaning of word. Same thing goes with English language.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think it's haram, because it helps people who don't understand Arabic, and people who think Arabic is too hard to read. Because Arabic is a difficult language.

Answer (score 0):

Transliterating Arabic to English is not haraam but it can cause confusion especially with words related to Islam. This is because the Arabic language has many different pronunciations and meanings. So it is better to avoid it.